# Can I use Post request instead of Delete in Angular?

Tags: php, angular, angular6

I have an application with CRUD functionality in admin panel and I was trying to Delete some items from DB but I unfortunately I have some CORS issues `(... Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.)` when I use Delete request from HttpClient. Apparently I don't have any problems with POST or GET and my question is if it is possible and "right" to use Post request and then do a delete query inside php and why should someone prefer Delete request over Post request for such actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the server does not allow for DELETE request from the client.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header need to explicitly name DELETE HTTP method.

According to REST specification you should not use POST request to DELETE resources. It could be confusing for other developers.

Comment: Okay I see.
You mean" header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS') ? Because it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Server is the one who decides whether allow for it or not. Do you have access to the server code?

Comment: I mean - the forementioned header has to be placed in server response to preflight request (OPTIONS) called handshake. Have a look for following resource, where whole process is comprehesivley described.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS